# Webpack setup to allow LESS overrides to take effect in imported NPM modules

Tags: npm, webpack, less, webpack-style-loader, webpack-plugin

I'm working on an app that is bundled using webpack.  The app is built out of a number of NPM modules hosted in a private NPM registry.  Some of these modules import LESS variables from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/):

```
// my-module-stylesheet.less
@import (reference) "~bootstrap/less/variables.less";

.widget {
    background:  @brand-primary;
}
```

When the module is compiled, this LESS code is compiled into CSS and bundled with the module's JavaScript file (using [less-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader)).

This works well, except in cases where my main application overrides Bootstrap's default styles in its own LESS file:

```
// my-app-stylesheet.less
@brand-primary: #d9534f; // red
```

These overrides *only* apply to styles defined directly in my app, as any styles defined in modules are already pre-compiled to CSS.  As a result, any components defined in a module don't reflect the overrides defined in my main app.

Here's a more visual explanation of the problem:

[image: Two red square that have different background colors]

How can I set up my webpack builds for both my NPM modules and my web application to allow for application-level LESS overrides that apply to imported modules?

Comment: A long time ago I had this problem. My conclusion was to not mix webpack with less. I only import a single less file through webpack less-loader, that is like the entry point of my styles. This way you can set up exactly the order of the imports in less. Since you want a Webpack solution, I am only commenting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Amida.  Having spent a few days thinking about this problem, I think I'm ending up in the same place you did.